# Combine 7z chunks on an AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, 7zip

I have compressed a file into several chunks using 7zip:

HAVE - the following saved in an AWS S3 Bucket:

```
pic.7z.001
pic.7z.002
pic.7z.003
pic.7z.004
pic.7z.005
```

Each chunk is 700 MB.

WANT - the following also saved in an AWS S3 Bucket:

```
first step: pic.7z
second step: a folder called 'pic'
```

I want to do it all on the AWS S3 if possible.

How do I unzip and combine these chunks to get a single file using python?

Comment: You can't do this on S3. You have to download the files somewhere, join and re-upload.

Comment: I thought as much. Therefore, I started downloading and joining the files. Is there a way to upload them as a 7z file to the bucket then extract them there to the needed folder then delete the 7z file?

Comment: s3 is only storage solution. You can't extract anything. You have to do operations such as extraction, joining in lambda function or ec2 instance if you don't want to leave aws.

Comment: I'll also add that lambdas are limited to 15 minutes of execution time. If your job takes longer than that you need to look into self managed ec2 or fargate.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. It is my first time dealing with AWS S3 and I am fairly new in my job so your feed back is greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do this in S3, since S3 is only responsible for storage. You can do this in AWS lambda. You can invoke one lambda function per chunk and load the chunk into memory since the max disk space is only 512 MB for each function. Then initialize a multipart upload, and use the S3 multipart upload functionality to upload each chunk to S3. Finally, complete the multipart upload and S3 will automatically concatenate all the parts together into one 7z file.

Comment: It wouldn't work in this situation as I have sometimes up to 12 part 700mb each, but it makes sense for smaller ones.